# Multi Reverse Geocoding API 500 Error

Tags: here-api

https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.json?app_id=MYID&app_code=MYCODE&gen=8&mode=retrieveAddress

Get Parameters

```
app_id=MYID
app_code=MYCODE
gen=8
mode=retrieveAddress
```

Headers

```
Content-Type=*
Cache-Control=no-cache
```

Post Body

```
prox=44.97750,-93.26899,50
prox=44.93909,-93.28083,50
```

Returns a 500 error with the response body being

```
{"type":"SystemError"}
```

This error doesn't provide me with any useful information as to what is wrong. Is there something wrong with my request or is this on Here's side?

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to the API description that should help you with a successful post request: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/request-first-multi-reverse-geocode.html

Looks like your post body doesn't include an "id". But you need that as otherwise you will not be able input to results, which is important when you don't limit maxresults to "1" and you are very likely get multiple results per input coordinate back.

I also recommend to set gen=9 and increase the radius from 50 to at least 250 meters. Because when your input point is further away than 50 meters from a road you can easily get back an area level fallback. Results are ranked by distance to input coordinate anyway, so a larger radius doesn't hurt at all.

```
id=0001&prox=44.97750,-93.26899,250
id=002&prox=44.93909,-93.28083,250
```

Comment: Please, advise how to do it in python with 'requests', not with 'geocoder' module.